# java: Make multi level dynamic jtree from database table

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i have make a database table like the following, but the rows can be more

```
id  Name     parent   
1  color      null        
2  red        1        
3  white      1         
4  green      1         
5  dark       4        
6  light      4
```

- To retrieve the table from database i already written the code following. i search all over the internet but unable to find the solution that's what i found, i am successful to make a connection with Db, and print the resultSet values using while loop , but unable to make jtree, i mean i make jtree but its not working as it should do.

```html
public class TreeDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TreeDemo
     */
    String Connection;
    Connection conn;
    Statement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    DefaultTreeModel model;
    
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, ObjClass> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public TreeDemo() {
        initComponents();

        model = (DefaultTreeModel) TreePro.getModel();

         // retrieve Jtree From dataBase
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Hr", "Hr");
            System.out.println("Connection Established");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts order by node_id");
            System.out.println("id  name    job" + rs);

            // Retrieve rs from DataBase

            
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("node_Id");
                String name = rs.getString("node_Name");
                String par = rs.getString("node_Parent");
                int lvl = rs.getInt("node_Level");
               System.out.println(id + "   " + name + "    " + par + " " + lvl);
     
   
     String parentId = rs.getString("node_Id");  
     String parentName = rs.getString("node_Name");
     String paren = rs.getString("node_Parent");
     int treeLvl = rs.getInt("node_Level");

     Map<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode> parentsMap
     = new HashMap<>();
        DefaultTreeModel tbl = (DefaultTreeModel) TreePro.getModel();
   DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tbl.getRoot();
   
  
DefaultMutableTreeNode Node1 = parentsMap.get("Root");




       Node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( paren );
       
       parentsMap.put(parentId, Node1 );
       root.add(Node1); 
 
     DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = parentsMap.get(parentName);

       parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( parentName );
       parentsMap.put(parentId, parent );
       Node1.add(parent);

          
            
            }   

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("connection error " + e);
        }
 
    }}}
```

Now it's creates jtree like this

```
Root
 Null
  -color
 color
  -red
 color
  -white
 color
  -green
 green
  -dark
 green
  -light
```

It should show jtree like this:

```
 Root
  _color
    -red
    -white
    _grenn
      -dark
      -light
```

Note: the jtree can be multilevel.

Comment: Since i am new to jtree your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks remarkably like the code & problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50246180/418556). Are you two in the same class with the same teacher?

Comment: Woww....  that's a co-incidence i could say

Comment: Any  suggestion @AndrewThompson ???

Comment: *"Any suggestion .. ???"* 1) Fix that stuck **?** key. 2) Use code formatting for Java code, rather than runnable snippet. (Try the button - it's not runnable). To do that, select the text and click the **`{}`** button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) Be patient.

Comment: Come on people any suggestion i have to submit the assignment tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrewThompson then i have to post my whole code to run on snippet, how can i do that, the stackoverflow will not allow me to enter a bluck of code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Let me allow to established my question, i have a table in database(values id, Name, Parent_ID, Level) . Now the main thing is that row can be 10, 4 or 20 thats why i have to make it dynamic. I write some code but in result the jtree(the jtree which i also mention) which make is not accurate as it should be.

Comment: if it's difficult for you to edit code without run on snippet then in that case  you can tell how to do it theoretically, your help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you. Because I haven't your database, I've used a two-dimensional array as data source. I hope it makes no problem for you to make your code as it shown in my example

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TreeExample implements Runnable {

    private static final Object NODES[][] =
            {{1, "color", null}, {2, "red", 1}, {3, "white", 1}, {4, "green", 1}, {5, "dark", 4}, {6, "light", 4}};

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        // use while loop to make you easer to switch to your result set.
        int index = 0;
        Map<Integer, DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodesMap = new HashMap<>();
        while (index < NODES.length) {
            Integer id = getValue(NODES[index], 0, Integer.class);
            Integer parentId = getValue(NODES[index], 2, Integer.class);
            String name = getValue(NODES[index], 1, String.class);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
            nodesMap.put(id, node);
            if (parentId == null) {
                root.add(node);
            } else {
                nodesMap.get(parentId).add(node);
            }
            index++;
        }
        JTree tree = new JTree(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        expandTree(tree);
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Tree test");
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        frm.setSize(300, 200);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private <T> T getValue(Object[] array, int index, Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(array[index]);
    }

    private void expandTree(JTree tree) {
        int row = 0;
        while (tree.getRowCount() > row) {
            tree.expandRow(row++);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TreeExample());
    }
}
```

Comment: i can post my database query if u want

Comment: @ShaunTait No, thanks! Simply try to adopt my code to your database results. It's not hard. And also you can learn something about trees.

Comment: can you please do it by result set ? sincce i new to java so its difficult for me to understand your code.

Comment: it will be great pleasure if u do it, then gradually i can understand the your above mention code too

Comment: how can i implement my result set in the above code?

Comment: @ShaunTait It's not "please do my job" site. Try to do it by yourself. And when you get new question, simply ask it here again. Please try at least to understand my code.

Comment: @ShaunTait you only need to replace the condition in `while` statement to your condition, and also insert your data extraction block instead of my calls of `getValue` method.

Comment: what is the purpose of this line return clazz.cast(array[index]);

Comment: @ShaunTait You don't need the method `getValue()` in your code. Simply extract the appropriate values from your result set row.

Comment: i try to do it, hope it will done, if i need to ask something more can i ask here?

Comment: @ShaunTait Yes. Try it. It's not to hard :)

Comment: yeah Thanks mate i hope i'll do it.

Comment: in your while loop nodes.lenght , i am writting Id but its gets error, what should i do

Comment: @ShaunTait You don't need the `NODES` array. Simply iterate over your `ResultSet` as you did it in your code. And extract the data also as you did it in your code.

Comment: i find it difficult to make solution of problems like the question i post, and you solve it like it was nothing. I am beginner, just starts my internship, what should i read or what should i do to be like you mate, @Sergiy Medvynskyy I want to be a person who can solve problem like you did. Any advice for me to become like you(any suggestion like what should i read or what i have to do, my intern is in java swing). your help will be appreciated man.

Comment: how much time approximately i will become a little like you,

Comment: @ Sergiy Please one last question in your time when you start, in how much time period you become a better programmer,?

Comment: There is a lot of information, but i am confuse from where i should start, mean what should be my part(for example i will do this, then this, then this, then i will be a better coder). so from where i should start.?

Comment: @ShaunTait Uff. Your questions are harder for me than write a solution for you. Ok. Try to play with algorythms. For example try to implement bubble sort using java. Next step: is to implement quick sort algorythm. Then try to build a tree with your own objects and iterate (traverse it). Good example for the last task is the source of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. When you do these tasks ask me for more ;)

Comment: Now about my expirience. My first program I wrote as I was 15. Now I'm in this job about 20 years, so I had time to learn something. I think you need at least some years to get the level of a junior developer. After that all goes easer ;)

Comment: hmmm some years(like 1,2 or 3?) to get the level of junior programmer, then in the meanwhile what should i do jobless ? lol.
BTW thanks @sergiy, i will implement bubble and quick sort algorithm, then ask you for more. I do hope you reply :)

Comment: @ShaunTait Why software developers get a good salary? Think about it ;)